# is there a quick way to fill out missing data in pandas dataframe w/o change the whole row?

Tags: python, pandas

suppose you have the following merged dataframe, notice index  2005 has three columns missing

```
#         HPI  Int_rate    US_GDP   LowHPI
#YEAR                                                  
#2001.0  80.0       2.0     50.0      50
#2002.0  85.0       3.0     55.0      51
#2003.0  88.0       2.0     65.0      52
#2004.0  85.0       2.0     55.0      50
#2005.0   NaN       NaN     NaN       53
```

If I have another dataframe or series looks like

```
([100,3,70],['HPI', 'Int_rate','US_GDP'])
```

Is there any way to use that to automatically fill out the missing columns? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that `another_df` has matching index:

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
         HPI  Int_rate  US_GDP  LowHPI
2001.0  80.0       2.0    50.0      50
2002.0  85.0       3.0    55.0      51
2003.0  88.0       2.0    65.0      52
2004.0  85.0       2.0    55.0      50
2005.0   NaN       NaN     NaN      53

In [51]: another_df
Out[51]:
        HPI  Int_rate  US_GDP
2005.0  100         3      70

In [52]: df = df.combine_first(another_df)

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
          HPI  Int_rate  LowHPI  US_GDP
2001.0   80.0       2.0      50    50.0
2002.0   85.0       3.0      51    55.0
2003.0   88.0       2.0      52    65.0
2004.0   85.0       2.0      50    55.0
2005.0  100.0       3.0      53    70.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) which overwrites `df` with all non null values from `another_df`:

```
df.update(another_df)
>>> df
      HPI  Int_rate  US_GDP  LowHPI
2001   80         2      50      50
2002   85         3      55      51
2003   88         2      65      52
2004   85         2      55      50
2005  100         3      70      53
```